# Как более элегантно реализовать функцию, по поиску нужного индекса в массиве?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

```
       const conditions = [
  {
    statuses: [1, 1, 'both'],
    buttonsByStep: {
      4: [{ id: '0a', text: 'continue next course' }],
      6: [{ id: '0b', text: 'continue next course'}]
    }
  },
  {
    statuses: [1, 0, 1],
    buttonsByStep: {
      4: [{ id: '1b', text: 'continue next training' }],
      6: [{ id: '3b', text: 'continue next training'}]
    }
  },
  {
    statuses: [1, 0, 0],
    buttonsByStep: {
      4: [{id: '2c', text: 'see more missions'}],
      6: [{ id: '5g', text: 'see more missions'}]
    }
  },
  {
    statuses: [0, 1, 'both'],
    buttonsByStep: {
      4: [
        { id: '4e', text: 'retake the text' },
        { id: '5g', text: 'continue next course' }
      ],
      6: [
        { id: '4te', text: 'retake the text' },
        { id: '5gjjf', text: 'continue next course' }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    statuses: [0, 0, 1],
    buttonsByStep: {
      4: [
        { id: '6f', text: 'retake the test' },
        { id: '7i', text: 'continue next training' }
      ],
      6: [
        { id: '8j', text: 'retake the test' },
        { id: '79g', text: 'continue next training' }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    statuses: [0, 0, 0],
    buttonsByStep: {
      4: [
        { id: '8yb', text: 'retake the text' },
        { id: '2hg', text: 'see more missions' }
      ],
      6: [
        { id: '8ibf', text: 'retake the text' },
        { id: '2cbg', text: 'see more missions' }
      ]
    }
  }
];


const userStatuses = { // аргументы для передачи в функцию
      passedTest: 1,
      hasNextCourse: 1,
      hasNextOngoingTraining: 1
    };
    const step = 4;

(userStatuses, step) => {
  const userValues = Object.values(userStatuses);
  const availableStatuses = conditions.map((condition) => condition.statuses);

  let searchIndex = 0;

  availableStatuses.forEach((statusArr, upperIndex) => {
    let counter = 0;
    statusArr.forEach((status, index) => {

      if (status === userValues[index]) {
        counter++;
      } else if (status === 'both') {
        counter++;
      }
    });

    if (counter === statusArr.length) {
      searchIndex = upperIndex;
    }
    counter = 0;
  });

  console.info(searchIndex);
};
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно более элегантно и лаконично реализовать данную функцию ? Суть её заключается в том что она проходит по коллекции conditions,собирает все поля statuses и смотрит совпадает ли свойства параметра userStatuses cо всеми элементами одного из массивов, возвращает index в случае успеха.
Одним элементом из массива statuses является строка 'both', означает что значение может быть либо 1 или 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен в элегантности. Но код работает и, вроде бы, в один проход по массиву.

```js
const conditions = [{
    statuses: [1, 1, 'both'],
    buttonsByStep: {
      4: [{
        id: '0a',
        text: 'continue next course'
      }],
      6: [{
        id: '0b',
        text: 'continue next course'
      }]
    }
  },
  {
    statuses: [1, 0, 1],
    buttonsByStep: {
      4: [{
        id: '1b',
        text: 'continue next training'
      }],
      6: [{
        id: '3b',
        text: 'continue next training'
      }]
    }
  },
  {
    statuses: [1, 0, 0],
    buttonsByStep: {
      4: [{
        id: '2c',
        text: 'see more missions'
      }],
      6: [{
        id: '5g',
        text: 'see more missions'
      }]
    }
  },
  {
    statuses: [0, 1, 'both'],
    buttonsByStep: {
      4: [{
          id: '4e',
          text: 'retake the text'
        },
        {
          id: '5g',
          text: 'continue next course'
        }
      ],
      6: [{
          id: '4te',
          text: 'retake the text'
        },
        {
          id: '5gjjf',
          text: 'continue next course'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    statuses: [0, 0, 1],
    buttonsByStep: {
      4: [{
          id: '6f',
          text: 'retake the test'
        },
        {
          id: '7i',
          text: 'continue next training'
        }
      ],
      6: [{
          id: '8j',
          text: 'retake the test'
        },
        {
          id: '79g',
          text: 'continue next training'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    statuses: [0, 0, 0],
    buttonsByStep: {
      4: [{
          id: '8yb',
          text: 'retake the text'
        },
        {
          id: '2hg',
          text: 'see more missions'
        }
      ],
      6: [{
          id: '8ibf',
          text: 'retake the text'
        },
        {
          id: '2cbg',
          text: 'see more missions'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];


const userStatuses = { // аргументы для передачи в функцию
  passedTest: 1,
  hasNextCourse: 1,
  hasNextOngoingTraining: 1
};
const step = 4; // не понял для чего нужно

console.log(init(conditions, userStatuses));

function init(conditions, userStatuses) {
  // Обходим массив conditions
  return conditions.findIndex(condition => {
    let check = true;
    let idx = 0
    // Обходим свойства userStatuses и сверяем с массивом
    // statuses.
    for (let prop in userStatuses) {
      if ((userStatuses[prop] !== condition.statuses[idx]) &&
        (condition.statuses[idx] !== 'both')) {
        check = false;
      }
      idx++;
    }
    return check;
});
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, ваше решение поинтересней. Насчёт step, он в контексте вопроса не важен, прошу прощения, что обозначил эту константу.